# Distributed Transaction Manager is disabled on SQL Azure, how to enable it?

Tags: azure

Well the doubt I have is how to enable the Distributed Transaction Manager in SQL Azure..anyone knows how to?  I am trying to make transactions over entity framework and I need this feature.

Comment: this question is off topic.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/handling-transactions-in-sql-azure.aspx

Comment: Why is this off-topic?  He's asking a direct question that pertains to SQL Azure

Comment: @DanielA.White - I don't see why it's off-topic, as it pertains to a programming feature available in SQL Server but not SQL Database (service). Would it be better at [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)? [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)? Since this seems like it's of interest to programmers, rather than dba's and server admins, I'd see it staying here on StackOverflow and remaining open. No?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to run SQL Server in a Virtual Machine to take advantage of DTC, as it's not supported by Windows Azure SQL Database service.

The complete comparison is available on TechNet, [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/996.compare-sql-server-with-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx). Drill down on **Guidelines and Limitations** --> **General Guidelines and Limitations** --> **Transaction Support**.

Answer (score 2):

Distributed transactions are not supported by SQL Azure